# Dúvida na hora da execução da função

Tags: javascript, objetos

```
const contatos = [
{
    nome: 'Alex Júnior',
    numero: '1234-5678'
},
{
    nome: 'Carolina Moya',
    numero: '1234-6789'
},
{
    nome: 'Fernando Jorge',
    numero: '12345-5567'
}
];
const [Alex , Carol] = contatos; 
function mostraNumero({numero}){  // aqui mora a dúvida
console.log(numero)
}
mostraNumero(Carol);
```

Na execução do código, quando chama a função `mostraNumero()`:

Quando invocado `mostraNumero(Carol)`, logo  `(Carol)` ----> `({numero})` passa a ser o parâmetro. Resumindo:

```
Carol = {
        nome: 'Carolina Moya',
        numero: '1234-6789'
    }
```

Como apenas escrevendo `{numero}` já conseguiu acessar a propriedade e valor, depois (`numero`) acessa o valor direto. Achei que tinha que usar a notação ponto (`.`) para acessar uma propriedade. Alguém pode esclarecer para mim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara esse conceito se chama Desestuturação, isso meio que consiste em vc criar uma variável com nome do atributo do objeto passando como valor o objeto...

Exemplo:

```
var obj = {
    nome: 'joao',
    idade: 23
};

var { idade } = obj;
```

O valor de idade será 23, pois vc pegou o valor idade do objeto obj, seria a mesma coisa você fazer:

```
var idade = obj.idade;
```

Se caso vc fizesse:

```
var { idade, nome } = obj;
```

O valor de idade também sera 23 e o valor de nome sera joão, porem em variáveis separadas ao envés de dentro de propriedades de um objeto.

No seu caso ali na função vc fez a mesma coisa porem com `array`, Carol é um objeto, e na hora da função `{ numero }` seria o numero do objeto Carol.